# How to join three tables in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have three tables:

- Chapter (ChapterNo, Desc)
- Lesson (LessonNO, Dec, ChapterNo)
- Case (CaseNo, Desc, LessonNo)

As you see, the three tables are all connected. What I want is to return all the chapters (even without lessons in it), all the lessons (even without cases in it) and all the cases.

I am sorry to say but I really don't have an idea so I have no sample code. I hope my explanations are enough.

Comment: Use Left Join for three tables

Comment: Sandip's query will help you out, but I advise you to inform your teacher you still struggle with the basic concepts of SQL. If you're having a hard time figuring this one out, it'll be hell later down the road.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

USE LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT
    C.*,
    L.*,
    CA.*
FROM Chapter C
LEFT JOIN Lesson L ON C.ChapterNo=L.ChapterNo
LEFT JOIN Case CA ON L.LessonNo=CA.LessonNo
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Left Join query in order to get your desired result

As for naming of tables. Don't use `Case` as table name because it is a reserved word for SQL.

`SELECT CH.ChapterNo,CH.Desc,LE.LessonNo,LE.Dec,CA.CaseNo,CA.Desc FROM Chapter CH
LEFT JOIN Lesson LE ON CH.ChapterNo = LE.ChapterNo LEFT JOIN Cases CA ON LE.LessonNo = CA.LessonNO`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM Chapter C
LEFT JOIN Lesson L ON C.ChapterNo=L.ChapterNo
LEFT JOIN Case CA ON L.LessonNo=CA.LessonNo
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * From Chapter c
   Left Join Lesson l On c.ChapterNo=l.ChapterNo  
   Left Join Case cs On cs.LessonNo=l. LessonNo
```